# connection error installing mongodb 4.0

Tags: mongodb

I am installing mongoDb 4.0 on windows 10, and I followed the installation guide.
The mongodb server is running as a service.
When I open Command Prompt and type: mongod, I got this message:

> 2018-07-13T13:47:41.173+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017

When I type mongo, I get this error:

> MongoDB shell version v4.0.0
>   connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
>   2018-07-13T13:48:04.245+0200 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: NetworkTimeout: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Socket operation timed out :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
>   @(connect):1:6
>   exception: connect failed

I tried to reinstall several times, but still the same.

Comment: check if firewall is not blocking 27017 port

Comment: When I turn of the firewall, mongoDB is working. I have checked that the port settings for MongoDb in AVG firewall, and they are correct, but still it is blocking when turned on.
I wrote to AVG support because I can not risk to work with the firewall open.

Comment: surprising. Sure you don't have additional firewall, integrated to windows for example.

Answer (score 2):

> if firewall is not blocking 27017 port – matthPen Jul 13 '18 at 13:18

I was trying to access MongoDB on Computer1(Server) with I.P Address as 10.7.9.103 from another Computer2(Client) with I.P Address as 10.1.2.107 in the same LAN network.

This is how you can do it:

(On the Server):

Step 1: Get the IP Address of the Host where you want to connect to.

Step 2: Find the mongod.cfg file at the location where you installed MongoDB(Default is: `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin`)

Step 3: Open with Notepad and add your Server's IP Address to the BindIP. E.g:

`# network interfaces
   net:
     port: 27017
     bindIp: 127.0.0.1,10.7.9.103`

Save it

Step 4: Open Fire Wall `Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall`
Then on the left side panel, click on Advanced Settings. 
Click on `Inbound Rules` on the left panel and click on `New Rule on the right panel`.

Step 5: Choose Port from the options and click on Next
Select `TCP`  and select `Specific local ports`. Enter the default port for MongoDB `27017` and click on Next
Select `Allow the connection` and click on NEXT
Check all 3 options `Domain, Private, Public` and click on NEXT
Give it a `Name` and an optional `Description` and click on `Finish`

Step 6: Restart your Server from `TaskManager >> Services >> MongoDB`.

(On the Client):
Run CMD as Administrator

Type `>cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin` (This is the path where you installed MongoDB)

Type `mongo --host 10.7.9.103` (The IP Adress is the IP Address of the Server).

Enjoy. :-)